# Rails consultar modelo

Tags: mvc, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql, model

Hola estoy con mis primeros pasos en Rails creando una app para un VideoClub, necesito saber si una película esta disponible o si ya esta prestada.
En el modelo Movie hay un atributo availability el cual es un booleano.
Tendría que crear un método en el modelo para acceder a ese atributo y ver si es true y luego usar lo que obtengo de ahí en otro método en el controlador para poder mostrar una lista de los disponibles y los prestados?

Me confunde que es lo que va en el modelo y que en el controlar.

Comment: ¿Y por que no simplemente en el controlador mediante el Active Record estableces una consulta que filtre usando como punto de partida ese atributo de clase?

Comment: Ya que incluso algunos te comentarán que la consulta no va ni en el modelo y tampoco en el controlador (*no es deber de ellos*), puedes pensar en una capa extra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si necesitas mostrar ambos, disponibles y no disponibles, solo llama a `Movie.all` en la acción de tu controlador y luego en la vista muestras un texto o otro dependiendo del valor de `availability`. Ahora, si solo necesitas mostrar los disponibles, en tu modelo puedes crear un scope:

```
class Movie
  scope :available, -> { where(availability: true) }
end
```

y luego en el controlador llamas a `Movie.available`.